# Use terminal to display image without losing focus

Tags: linux, image, bash, imagemagick, displayobject

I have a bash-script in which I want to display an image to the user. This is possible using ImageMagick's `display`.

```
display image.png
```

But now the focus of the terminal window is lost, and is placed to the image. To continue my bash-script I have to ask the user to click on the terminal before continuing. This is unwanted behaviour.

Is there a way to display an image without losing the focus of my bash terminal? I want it to get it work on Ubuntu Linux (12.04).

[image: Focus lost]

Comment: You could use `wmctrl`...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a not-too-awkward solution using `wmctrl`:

```
wmctrl -T master$$ -r :ACTIVE: ; display image.png & sleep 0.1 ; wmctrl -a master$$
```

To explain, I'll break it down into steps:

1. `wmctrl -T master$$ -r :ACTIVE:`

   To control a window, `wmctrl` needs to know its name, which by default is its window title.  So, this step assigns the current window to a unique name `master$$` where the shell will expand `$$` to a process ID number.  You may want to choose a different name.
2. `display image.png &`

   This step displays your image as a "background" process. The image window will grab focus.
3. sleep 0.1

   We need to wait enough time for `display` to open its window.
4. `wmctrl -a master$$`

   Now, we grab focus back from `display`.  If you chose a different name for your master window in step 1, use that name here in place of `master$$`.

If `wmctrl` is not installed on your system, you will need to install it.  On debian-like systems, run:

```
apt-get install wmctrl
```

`wmctrl` supports Enlightenment, icewm, kwin, metacity, sawfish, and all other EWMH/NetWM compatible X-window managers.

#### Alternative approach that doesn't require knowing the window title

First, get the ID of the current window:

```
my_id=$(wmctrl -l -p | awk -v pid=$PPID '$3 == pid {print $1}')
```

We can now use this ID in place of a window title.  To launch `display` while maintaining focus in the current window:

```
display image.png & sleep 0.1 ; wmctrl -i -a "$my_id"
```

Comment: Great! This is one complete answer. I had not heart of `wmctrl`, it works as advertised!

Comment: You can poll for the opened window instead of hoping your `sleep` will be a sufficient duration with a loop like this: `(while true; do wmctrl -l | egrep -iq 'imagemagick:' && break; sleep 0.1s; done)`

Answer (score 1):

*in addition to [John1024 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25586176/4827341).*

---

yet another way to get wid of active window:

```
$ xdotool getwindowfocus
```

and set focus:

```
$ xdotool windowfocus <wid>
```

so the full command will look like this (note the option `-i`, it is important!):

```
$ wid=$(xdotool getwindowfocus); display image.png & sleep 0.1; xdotool windowfocus $wid
```

---

p.s. read about [xdotool](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xdotool/info).

Answer (score 0):

Without losing the focus of terminal you can use **sublime text** to open any image

> `subl` image.png

Comment: `subl` grabs the focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `picterm`, it was created for this purpose: https://github.com/artemsen/picterm